# Where to get Ethereum dapp data by daily users?

Tags: dapps, web3.py, python

I looking to create a site similar to https://www.stateofthedapps.com/rankings/platform/ethereum and I am wondering how they are getting the data.  I need to retrieve the icon, category, total daily volume, users and balance.  I plan to load it into a db and refresh the data every 4 hours.

I've found tons of examples for building dapps but not programmatically accessing dapp data.

Answer (score 0):

Found what I was looking for here...

https://state-of-the-dapps.github.io/slate/#usage